# How do I generate stereo images from mono camera?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a stationary mono camera which captures a single image frame at some fps.

Assume the camera is not allowed to move,how do I generate a stereo image pair from the obtained single image frame? Is there any algorithms exists for this? If so, are they available in Open-CV?

Answer (score 4):

To get a *stereo* image, you need a stereo camera, i.e. a camera with two calibrated lenses. So you cannot get a stereo image from a single camera with traditional techniques.

However, with the magic of *deep learning*, you can obtain the [depth image from single camera](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Liu_Deep_Convolutional_Neural_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf).

---

And no, there's no builtin OpenCV function to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The most common use of this kind of techniques is in 3D TVs, which often offer 2D-to-3D conversion, and thus mono to stereo conversion.

Various algorithms are used for this, you can look at [this state of the art report](http://insy.ewi.tudelft.nl/content/converting-2d-3d-survey).

Answer (score 2):

There is also optical way for this.

If you can add binocular prisms/mirrors to your camera objective ... then you could obtain real stereoscopic image from single camera. That of coarse need access to the camera and setting up the optics. This also introduce some problems like wrong auto-focusing , need for image calibration, etc.

[image: img]

You can also merge Red/Cyan filtered images together to maintain the camera full resolution.

Comment: I was hoping someone would post a solution relying on splitting the optical path. Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a publication which might be helpful [Stereo Panorama with a single Camera](http://pt4pano.com/sites/default/files/editor/cvpr99-stereopan.pdf).

You might also want to have a look at the opencv [camera calibration module](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) and a look at [this](http://nzphoto.tripod.com/sterea/stereotake.htm) page.